# Continuity of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\mu$ be a measure on a $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$. $A,A_1,A_2\ldots\in\mathcal{A}$. Then it is
> >     $$
> > A_n\nearrow A\implies\mu(A_n)\nearrow\mu(A).
> > $$

I have a problem to understand the following proof:

Set $A_0:=\emptyset$. Because of the monotony it is $0=\mu(A_0)\leq\mu(A_1\leq\mu(A_2\leq\cdots$.

It is

$$
A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=\biguplus_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})
$$

and because of the $\sigma$-additivity and the subtractivity it is
$$
\mu(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})=\sup_{k\geq 1}\sum_{i=1}^k\underbrace{\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})}_{=\mu(A_i)-\mu(A_{i-1})}=\sup_{k\geq 1}\mu(A_k).
$$

---

There are to things that I do not understand:

(1) Subtractivity means: If $\mu(Z)<\infty$ one can write $\mu(W\setminus Z)=\mu(W)-\mu(Z)$. But why can I do that here, from where do I know that $\mu(A_{i-1})<\infty$?

(2) Why is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})=\sup_{k\geq 1}\sum_{i=1}^k\underbrace{\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})}_{=\mu(A_i)-\mu(A_{i-1})}?
$$

Why not:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k\underbrace{\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i-1})}_{=\mu(A_i)-\mu(A_{i-1})}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(A_k)?
$$

Is the $\lim$ and the $\sup$ equal here? And if yes, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad (1), you don't know that $\mu(A_1) < \infty$, unless that has been stated as a premise. However, if any of the $A_n$ has infinite measure, the monotonicity gives you $\mu(A) \geqslant \mu(A_n) = +\infty$ and there is nothing to show. Still, the assumption must be made explicit.

Ad (2), all the terms in the sum are non-negative, hence the sequence of partial sums is nondecreasing, and that means the supremum is the limit. At least if you allow $+\infty$ as a limit. If you insist on a $\lim$ being finite, when the sum is infinite, you must use $\sup$. If you have no qualms writing $\lim \mu(A_n) = +\infty$ [when that is the case], whether you use $\lim$ or $\sup$ is entirely a matter of taste.

Comment: Ad (1): Why is there nothing to show, if one $A_n$ has infinite measure? Ad (2): I think the sum can be $+\infty$. Nevertheless: Why do I have to use $\sup$ if the $\lim$ has to be finite?

Comment: Since $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$, if any $A_n$ has infinite measure, so have all the following, hence $\lim \mu(A_n) = \sup \mu(A_n) = +\infty$, and we have the equality $\mu(A) = \sup \mu(A_n)$ without further ado. Ad (2), if you [the author of the book] reserve the notation $\lim$ for finite limits, you can't use $\lim \mu(A_n)$ in case it's $+\infty$. Since nobody (well, let's hope) puts a finiteness restriction on $\sup$, using $\sup$ works whether the limit is finite or not. If you allow a limit to be infinite, there is no problem writing $\lim \mu(A_n)$.

Comment: And what's with writing $\limsup$? Is it the same to write $\lim$ or $\sup$ or $\limsup$?

Comment: In the case here, where we have a monotonically nondecreasing sequence, all three coincide. And in this case, also $\liminf$ is the same. Whenever $\lim$ exists (in $[-\infty,+\infty]$), we have $\liminf = \lim = \limsup$, but the equality $\lim = \sup$ needs monotonicity.

Comment: And if f.e. $\limsup$ is in $[-\infty,\infty]$, is then $\limsup=\lim$? Sorry, it is a little bit difficult to understand these relationships.

Comment: No, $\limsup$ exists always in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, from that you cannot deduce the existence of the limit. The limit exists if and only if $\liminf = \limsup$, and then it coincides with the two.

Comment: I ask because in a proof I saw that the $\limsup$ is 0. But it was to show that the $lim$ is 0.

Comment: If all terms are nonnegative, then you know that $\liminf \geqslant 0$. Since always $\liminf \leqslant \limsup$, in that situation $\limsup = 0$ implies that the limit exists and is $0$. But if you can't know that the $\liminf$ is non-negative, showing that the $\limsup$ is $0$ is not sufficient to deduce the existence of the limit. But it likely was the case that everything was $\geqslant 0$, and then it suffices.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. This is indeed the case!